# Is it possible to render a page with express without any template engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm the beginner at express and would like to ask you whether it is possible. Maybe it is just stupidity but I haven't found the clear answer yet. Thanks for answers.

res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])

Comment: you can serve static files if you want that or use `res.send('hello world');`

Comment: you simply need to pass valid HTML as your `view` param. It does not matter if this makes use of a template engine or not

Comment: I don't think you will be able to make use of locals variables in this case. If it is about serving static files, you can directly use `res.send` to send files.

Comment: Of course, it is possible: any template engine is just a server-side script that process your code and outputs some HTML.

Comment: @Artem there are also client side template engines

Comment: @messerbill sure, but we are talking about page rendering process on a server-side.

Comment: If you want to dive into how it works, I would suggest you to take a glance at this library: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/. It is very simple, but gives enough knowledge on how each template engine works.

Comment: Express by itself provides a small example of how you can write a templater on your own: http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html.